# how to setup continuos deployment from docker-hub to AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-deployment, dockerhub, amazon-ecs

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for my micro-services. Currently I use TravisCI to pull the code from Github upon check-in, build the docker image and push it to DockerHub. I tried using docker cloud(previously knows as Tutum), which provides automatic deployment feature to AWS EC2 instance but the deployment sometimes recreates the container and the service endpoint URL changes, which is not desirable.

I am exploring amazon's ECS and its tasks , but I can not find any reference for how to setup continuos deployment to ECS when a new image is pushed to docker hub. 
Anybody has any experience doing the setup ?

Answer (score 1):

with ECS you would basically have CI detect a change to docker hub and update your task definition/service.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx32RHFZHXY6ME1/Set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-Jenkins-and-Amazon-ECS

Answer (score 0):

For this I use the wonderful ecs-deploy script from here:

https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy

After my container has been built and deployed to dockerhub it's simply a matter of:

```
ecs-deploy -k $AWS_KEY -s $AWS_SECRET -r $AWS_REGION -c $CLUSTER_NAME -n $SERVICE_NAME -i $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

and that does it.